# Forward TFTP to different server

Tags: dhcp, tftp

I have Ubuntu 14.04 with DHCP running, I have to forward TFTP requests to Windows Deployment server, how do I do this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the next-server parameter in dhcp.conf to point to the tftp server.

An example from a LTSP entry which does what you want.

```
host thinclient {
  hardware ethernet   00:00:00:00:00:00;
  fixed-address       192.168.1.100;
  next-server         192.168.1.1;
  option root-path    "/path/to/root";
  filename            "/path/to/boot/image";
}
```

In this case the thin client boots, is given the .1.100 address and is pointed to 192.168.1.1 for tftp.